# Is there any way reading from a txt file and matching keywords

Tags: java, arrays, file

Hello i want to make a java programme, which will read a txt file and then it should match those keywords with, given words in programme.
I want to match keywords with my own words in array ?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It'll work better if you fix all the compile errors first. --- I think the important part behind the link @SotiriosDelimanolis gave, is the part about *Verifiable* in this sub-link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, however you should read it all.

Comment: please help if u know

Answer (score 0):

I try with your code (more or less)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("READ URL");
    String input = scanner.next();
    try {
        URL url1=new URL(input);
        System.out.println(url1);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

With the input www.example.com fail because don't have protocol but with the input http://www.example.com works fine.